# How to set iframe width for a different class in same page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, iframe

I am saving the you tube iframe video with different width and height for feeds and comments in database.For feeds i am saving the video with height 580px and width 320px.For comments,i am passing the height 480px and width 280px. In same page i had set the iframe like below,

```
 object, iframe{
        height: 320px;
        width: 580px;
    }
```

Why i had added above is because user can add twitch and vimeo video also.To override the twitch and video script's iframe height and width i added.Is it possible to set the iframe and object width and height for individual class.I tried like below,

```
  object, iframe .feed-text{
            height: 280px;
            width: 40px;
        }
```

to show the video in comments i tried the above with class name but not worked for me.

I need to set iframe height and width for two different class.Is it possible.

Comment: Umm...you need to use `iframe.feed-text` with no space if the `feed-text` is the class of the iframe.

Comment: What have you tried at the moment? Probably best if you provide a fiddle for us.

Comment: @Ohgodwhy In comments portion i changed as per your word and it worked.If i come to twitch video having the problem because twitch video is saving into db with default width and i am not changing the height/width.Here i get the correct video if i remove the class.If i add class it is rendered with the default height/width saved in db.Any help is good.Thanks